# Can I compare DB entities by equals in hashcode with different fields?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, hash, equals

I have Question DB entity:

```
public class Question {
    @Id
    @UuidGenerator
    @Column(name = "question_id")
    private String questionId;

    @Column(name = "text")
    private String text;

    @Column(name = "correct_answer_description")
    private String correctAnswerDescription;

    @Column(name = "correct_answers_number")
    private Integer correctAnswersNumber;

    @ToString.Exclude
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Answer> answers = new ArrayList<>();

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name = "question_answers",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "fk_question_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "fk_quiz_id")
    )
    @ToString.Exclude
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    private Set<Quiz> quizzes = new HashSet<>();

    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    @CreationTimestamp
    @Column(name = "creation_date")
    private LocalDateTime creationDate;

    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    @UpdateTimestamp
    @Column(name = "update_date")
    private LocalDateTime updateDate;
}
```

And I also have QuestionCreationForm

```
public class QuestionCreationForm {
    @NotBlank
    private String text;
    private String correctAnswerDescription;
    @NotNull
    @Range(min = 0)
    private Integer correctAnswerNumber;

    @NotEmpty(message = "Answers should not be empty")
    @Valid
    @Builder.Default
    @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
    private List<AnswerApi> answers = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

My goal is create **save ** endpoint from set like this:

```
    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<List<QuestionApi>> save(final @PathVariable("quizId") String quizId,
                                                  final @RequestBody @NotEmpty   Set<QuestionCreationForm> questions) {
        final List<QuestionApi> createdQuestions = questionService.create(questions, quizId)
                                                                  .stream()
                                                                  .map(questionMapper::toApi)
                                                                  .collect(Collectors.toList());

        return new ResponseEntity<>(createdQuestions, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

But I have some problem in service:

```
    public List<Question> save(final Set<QuestionCreationForm> createdQuestionsApi,
                               final String quizId) {
        final Quiz quiz = quizService.findById(quizId)
                                     .orElseThrow(() -> new QuizEntityNotFoundException(ENTITY_NOT_FOUND_BY_ID_EXCEPTION, quizId));
        final Set<Question> existedQuestions = questionRepository.findAllByQuizIdWithAnswers(quizId);
        final Set<Question> createdQuestion = createdQuestionsApi.stream()
                                                                 .map(questionMapper::toDomain)
                                                                 .collect(Collectors.toSet());

        //The problem here, method use equals and hashcode, but fields like creat and update date does no exist
        //So have no unique entities and this is cause to problem with create same question
        final var subtract = CollectionUtils.subtract(createdQuestion, existedQuestions);

        if (subtract.isEmpty()) {
            throw new QuizBadRequestException(QUESTION_EMPTY_ARRAY_EXCEPTION);
        }

        subtract.forEach(question -> question.addQuiz(quiz));

        return questionRepository.saveAll(subtract);
    }
```

The main problem, is that **CollectionUtils.subtract** (take only elems that exist in collection1 and do not exist in collection 2) used equals method that is used for all fields in db entity. So my question is, what is best option to choose:

1. Do not use quizId and others fields in equals but I think is not ok, because on my opinion in DB entities level, this entites realy different
2. Return from DB DTO entity, and compare by this dto
3. Create is same method, and us if-else statements to check for unique
4. Your variants

I`m want to find best solution for comparing 2 entites by different equals and hash code in different situations